# HaProxy X-Forwered-For sends when already present incoming request

Tags: haproxy, x-forwarded-for

I'm trying to get **`X-Forwarded-For`** when original client request contains that header and pass it to the application layer in using HAProxy.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That does not require any configuration.  All incoming request headers are forwarded to the back-end unless you configure the proxy to modify or remove them.

Comment: How can I make sure that X-Forwarded-For is just added only when already available with request

Comment: That isn't a safe configuration.  The proxy should eithet always add it or never add it -- otherwise a malicious user can forge the header.  Please describe the reason for this setup.

Comment: I don't want to add x-forwarded-for in headers with haproxy IP So I can get real users those are coming over proxy.